# Is possible to play at same time two or more sound files with Soundmanager2 synchronously?

Tags: javascript, soundmanager2

Is possible to play at same time two or more sound files with Soundmanager2? How to play synchronous?

The best solution that i achieved is in the example: [enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/colepopiku/3/edit?html,js,output)

Cheers,
Ricardo

Comment: i know, but with long files the play action is not synchronous. :(

Comment: Is it not synchronous just the first (few) time you play it, or always? If it's always, it could be the CPU or other hardware issue, but if it's only the first time, you probably just need to wait for all the sounds to load. Can you make an example?

Comment: The CPU is fine. How can i preload all files? If i have 7 files or plus, can i play them, just by:   soundManager.play("1");
    soundManager.play("2");   soundManager.play("3");
    soundManager.play("4");   soundManager.play("5");
    soundManager.play("6"); ...